# Number of DB connection using

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

We are using spring, jpa, hibernate, oracle and java for our web application. While deploying our web application, it uses certain amount of connection from the DB. So i need to find the
following

1. Total number of available connection
2. number of connection currently using
3. number of free connection.

Is it possible? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. When I look in the net, i got the idea of find the above in oracle db as the Admin privileged user. But I need to do it in our application or the external program.

Comment: Are you using a connection pool? If not, the number of connections is equal to the number of times Hibernate calls `DataSource#getConnection()` and doesn't close the resulting `Connection` object.

Comment: we are using ComboPooledDataSource

Comment: Then the number of connections depends on the configuration. What's your max connections setting?

Comment: our maximum connection size is 500. but how to find the number of connection currently using?

Comment: You'll have to find some way to reference the connection pool and check how many `Connection` references it has.

Comment: Depends how you initialize it. If it's a Spring bean, inject it somewhere. I do believe you'll have to use reflection to get the field holding all the references. It won't be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the MyOra tool which has all the key features regarding to DB the developer expect. http://myorasql.com/         and may try with the following oracle query
http://blog.sergkazakov.com/2010/10/check-oracle-number-of-connections.html

Answer (score 0):

You're using connection pooling so the maximum number of connections is specified in your configuration settings.

Assuming that all the sessions are using a single username and that no other sessions use that same username

```
select count(*)
  from gv$session
 where username = <<username your application is using>>
```

will show you how many sessions are currently open.

I'm not quite sure what it means to you for a connection to be "free" in this context.  My guess would be to subtract the number of open sessions from the configured maximum number of sessions but I'm not sure if that's what you're after or not.